# Check file_get_contents close because of timeout

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have a script to download image from China server, so image might not be able to download correctly like only partial image shown because of CDN. Guess because of timeout?

Any ways to check image is not downloaded completely?

`$content` would not equal to `FALSE` if partial image is downloaded

```
function addNewFile($url) {
    $newFileName = 'newFileName.png';
    $content = @file_get_contents($url);
    if ($content === FALSE) {
        echo ' - sleep 30 seconds and try again... ' . "\n";
        sleep(30);
        return addNewFile($url);
    } else {
        file_put_contents($newFileNameInLocal, $content);
    }
}
```

Correct image should be

[image]

But, I get

[image]

Comment: use curl request on the image and parse the Content-Length on the HTTP response. This will give you Image size and apply your re-try logic till you fetches the image

Comment: ok let me try it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ini_set('max_execution_time', 6000);` as beginning of the file..By the way you can increase run time of the file..

Comment: I think the server just stop sending me bytes because if I retry the program, my image is fine.

Comment: I think they blocked your request in server

Comment: they say it is CDN